# need AT command for sim reset

Tags: at-command

is there any AT command which can reset the sim in a gsm usb modem. now i am using a MOBIDATA E66 modem. so if any can provid me the command or know similar command then please help me.

when i communicate with the sim if the connection is lost or modem is disconnected then the sim remains at that state (say i opened a menu and then got disconnected). so i need a reset command which will send the sim to the initial state.

thanks..arefin

Answer (score 9):

Have you tried `AT!GRESET` or `AT!RESET`? I don't know if they are supported in your modem.

If none of them are working, use `AT+CLAC` to get the modem's available commands and search for some kind of RESET/RST command.

If you can't find a reset command, try turning off and on the modem radio using `AT+CFUN=0` and `AT+CFUN=1`.

Comment: i find the solution by at+reset

Answer (score 6):

On TC35i (and probably elsewhere too) you can use `AT+CFUN=1,1` (the second `1` means reset). You need to reconnect the serial interface though.

Comment: AT+CFUN=1,1 works for Sierra Wireless HL78xx.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old but giving my answer for those who will find the same issue in future.

Do the *soft* restart of gsm and that should solve the problem via an at command. For u-blox chips it is `AT+CFUN=1,16`.

I did it and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

For Quectel EC21 modem Im use:

```
AT+CFUN=0
// delay
AT+CFUN=1
```

This is enough for me, but also possible to send:

```
AT+CFUN=1,1
```

To reset the ME itself

Answer (score 0):

Press x for back to Main Menu, and wait many seconds. When displayed OK0, input the password. Default password is 1234.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but giving my answer for those who will find the same issue in future.

Do the *soft* restart of gsm and that should solve the problem via an at command. For u-blox chips it is `AT$ENHRST=1, 0`.

I did it and it work like a wonder.

Answer (score 0):

I am using **SIM800L**:

According to datasheet

`ATZ` *resets configurations*  (tested and works)

`AT+CDSCB`resets *Cell Broadcast* (tested and does not work)

Answer (score 0):

I have sim issue device
one time data or clock the connection (contact) lost in sim slot , by the time sim network it will lost, and how will get back sim network.

without restart the device i need do

before sim connection lost

```
lte_gps_test 'AT+CNUM'

AT+CNUM
+CNUM: ,"918431234564",129
```

After sim connection lost

```
lte_gps_test 'AT+CNUM'
```

modem_response:

```
AT+CNUM
ERROR
```

it will come continues

Answer (score 0):

I am using Quectel M66

according to the datasheet, You can use commands like AT+QPOWD==1 Which would simulate a Device reboot.

******AT+QPOWD Power off******

**Example**
AT+QPOWD=0

OK //Urgent power off, returned OK

AT+QPOWD=1

NORMAL POWER DOWN //Normal power off, send out URC“NORMAL
POWER DOWN”

2.21. AT+CMEE Report Mobile Equipment Error

AT+QPOWD Power off

Write Command

AT+QPOWD=

Response

When =0
OK

When =1

NORMAL POWER DOWN

Maximum Response Time 300ms

[image]